# JAVA consumer-producer multi-threaded application - flow of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I was practicing this famous application and have a question. I found there are 4000 Q/A on this topic in this site, but none of them is related to this point and hence asking this question.

Here is the simple code -

```
class Resource {
    int contents;
    boolean available = false;
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    private Resource resource;

    public Producer(Resource c) {
        resource = c;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            synchronized (resource) {
                while (resource.available == true) {
                    //System.out.println("Producer -> calling wait");
                    try {
LINE 1                  resource.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }
LINE 2          resource.contents = i;
                resource.available = true;
                //System.out.println("Producer -> calling notify");
                resource.notify();
                System.out.println("Producer " + " put: " + resource.contents);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    private Resource resource;

    public Consumer(Resource c) {
        resource= c;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            synchronized (resource) {
                while (resource.available == false) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer -> calling wait");
                    try {
LINE 3                  resource.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
LINE 4          resource.available = false;
                //System.out.println("Consumer -> calling notify");
                resource.notify();
                System.out.println("Consumer " + " got: " + resource.contents);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ProducerConsumerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource c = new Resource ();
        Producer p1 = new Producer(c);
        Consumer c1 = new Consumer(c);
    }
}
```

And here is the output -

```
#1 Producer  put: 0
#2 Consumer  got: 0
#3 Consumer -> calling wait
#4 Producer  put: 1
#5 Consumer  got: 1
#6 Consumer -> calling wait
#7 Producer  put: 2
#8 Consumer  got: 2
```

So here is the flow of code -

```
#1 Since available=false, Producer will go to LINE 2, make available=true and notify the other thread.
#2 Since available=true, Consumer will go to LINE 4, make available=false and notify the other thread.
#3 So now code should go back to the Producer thread. But why Consumer is entering it's own wait() block at LINE 3?
```

Am I missing something simple? Can you please explain?

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> 3 So now code should go back to the Producer thread. But why Consumer
>   is entering it's own wait() block at LINE 3?

well consumer thread will continue to run after it makes `available=false` and notify the other thread. Till  producer thread does not make available=true it will call wait and blocked.

Best way to implement the producer/consumer pattern is through [BlockingQueue](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem)

Here is the [example](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem)

Comment: Hi Sach - thanks a lot for the answer. So the point is the Consumer thread will continue to run - it will traverse back and forth within it's block until it calls wait() and then the control will go to the other thread. I missed this point. Cheers from my end!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your threads are coordinating their activity. When the Producer is sleeping it isn't waiting for resource. When the Consumer calls resource.notify() it is possible that no Producer is waiting for the resource.

As @[M Sach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802050/m-sach) has already pointed out, the Consumer thread is free to continue processing.

At this point the two threads are not coordinating with each other via resource, so the observed behaviour seems to be as expected from a running Consumer and a sleeping Producer.

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, the code is not perfect, i just picked up from some internet site for easy understanding. I agree that after one thread calls notify(), there is no such communication between the threads. As I commented, I understood the real point that thread will continue to run. I tried to make both the answers as accepted, but unfortunately I can do only one! Thanks from my end!

Comment: Hi, I am again confused! Please excuse me. In this case when the code has reached LINE 4, why the code will again come back to LINE 3? Why the Consumer thread will continue to run? If I remove the `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` line, even then LINE 3 is being executed. I am not really getting the point - will be thankful if you can explain.

Comment: LINE 4 sets resource.available = false, so the next time the Consumer runs through the for loop it will go to LINE 3 unless the Producer has set resource.available = true in the meantime. Due to the sleep in the Producer thread, it's likely that resource.available is still false.

Comment: With the for line removed, one way for LINE 3 to be called is if the Consumer thread is scheduled before the Producer thread. resource.available will have its initial value of false so execution can reach LINE 3 even there is no loop. This comes back to my original point that the threads don't coordinate their activity - at least not for all possible execution paths.